# Unexpected StringIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I was doing a problem where I had to delete characters from a String if the adjacent characters had same value. This is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SuperReducedStringRe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = in.next();
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(str);
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0;i < str.length()-1; i++) {
            if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1)) {
                s.delete(i,i+2);
                i=-1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

I check and re-checked for invalid indices but couldn't find one.Can someone help me find out when and how did I go out of permissible indices?

Comment: Hint: if you delete some characters from the `StringBuilder`, it's not the same length as it was. Suppose you start with "xxxxxxxxxxx"... you'll still end up looping 10 times, but by the end your `StringBuilder` won't be long enough. You should be able to see this by stepping through carefully in a debugger.

Comment: Where's the stack trace? Use the debugger Luke...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are operating on **one** variable and performing a check on **another** variable
See:

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++) // performing a check on str, whereas
```

and

```
s.delete(i,i+2); // updating s(deleting the char from s)
```

Change

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length()-2;i++)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I missed that I was checking for str.length()-1. About the second point, I think i<s.length()-1 is correct because that way when I compare (s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(i+1)), I am comparing the penultimate and the last element of the String in that final for loop iteration. Also, I don't go out of bound when using s.delete(i, i+2) because i+2 (end index in delete() function) is exclusive. So elements from i to i+1 will get deleted, where i+1 is the last allowed index for the String. So, I'm not actually using (i+2)th index as it is exclusive in the delete() function.

Comment: @AkhilRanjan You are right. I missed out the fact that in delete the 2nd arg is exclusive not inclusive. Also you can mark the answer as "Accepted" if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As JonSkeet has pointed out, you are ignoring the fact that deleting from a `StringBuilder` reduces its length.

Instead of:

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
```

Use

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++){
```

---

But what about `ch`? You never use that. And you don't need to use a `StringBuilder`, you can operate directly on the array:

```
int dst = 0;
int src = 0;
while (src < ch.length) {
  // Keep the character at src.
  ch[dst] = ch[src++];

  // Skip past all adjacent characters which are the same.
  while (src < ch.length && ch[src] == ch[dst]) {
    ++src;
  }

  // Move the dst pointer along, so the next char we keep doesn't overwrite the previous.
  ++dst;
}
// Now build a string from the first dst characters in ch.
System.out.println(new String(ch, 0, dst));
```